# iOS: zooming an image with a button

Tags: ios, xcode, zooming, scrollview

I have an imageView as the background for the application. I have a button on top of the background. I want to press that button and have an animation of the background image being zoomed in. What is the best way to solve this problem? Should I use scrollview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that using transform in an animation block is the best way.
You can do something like this :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
{
    [yourImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5)];
}];
```

and to place it back on the initial position you just need to do this :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
{
    [yourImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(80, 50, 150, 40);
[myButton setTitle:@"Your button!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"]];     
[self.view addSubview:myButton];

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
   self.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 150.0f);
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"Zoom" context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
   self.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f);
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Don't start the animation in the action method, it will collide with the button animation. Post it to the main queue in a block and it will look a lot nicer. good answer though!

Answer (score 0):

```
swift 4

    func zoomOut(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async{[weak self] in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {[weak self] in
            self?.imageView.transform = .identity
        })
    }
}

func zoomIn(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async{[weak self] in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {[weak self] in
            self?.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        })
    }
}
```